# Change database and execute update query (T- Transact)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

Could anyone face with issue like me?

I need to update some rows in table, but I don't know exact name of database. I am able to figure out name with:

```
Select name 
from sys.databases 
where name like '%%'
```

and then I need to execute update query, but I can't because I don't know how to force SQL server change database.

```
use "name of database"

update table
set column1 = column1 + 1
```

I tried to declare variable and set it as exact name of database.

```
*EXEC ('use ' + '@dbname')
update table
set column1 = column1 + 1*
```

In this case, I got error about invalid object "table"

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use SQL Servers [sp_executeslql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. Utilising this function you could write some sql like the sample below.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseToUse  VARCHAR(100),
        @SQLToRun       VARCHAR(200);

SELECT  @DateBaseToUse = 'MyDataBaseName';

SELECT @SQLToRun = 'UPDATE ' + @DatabaseToUse  + '.dbo.Table SET Column1 = Column1 + 1';

Execute sp_executesql @SQLToRun;
```

You should replace the .dbo. with the name of your Schema.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my typo. I read it twice before posting and I didn't notice :-)